# In Bash How to remove substring matching from back of the string

Tags: bash

version=0.1.2-2-gb12431b-3.4.5

What is the best utility in bash to remove the substring starting from hyphen from back of the string(-3.4.5).

I want the new_version=0.1.2-2-gb12431b, with the substring removed. Any suggestion on what is the right way to do it.

Comment: Hmm. There are a number of questions this is arguably duplicative of, but I'm still looking for one with answers I like. :)

Answer (score 5):

[Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) (prior link is to relevant man page section):

```
new_version=${version%-*}
```

Because this is only a single `%`, the expression is evaluated as non-greedy, so it stops at the first dash.

Using a parameter expansion avoids any call out to external tools -- cut, awk, sed, etc -- and is thus far more efficient.

---

See also:

- [The Bash-Hackers Parameter Expansion Page](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)
- [BashFAQ #73](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) ("How can I use parameter expansion?")
- [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) ("How can I do string manipulations in bash?")
- [The BashSheet section listing available parameter expansions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet#Parameter_Operations)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Couldn't believe it is so simple :).